# Is there a git option to force the usage of -- (dash dash) for file paths?

Tags: git

There is a very important distinction between

```
git checkout something
git checkout -- something
```

The first one will try to switch branches, the latter will discard changes in the file called `something` which is a destructive operation. When there is no branch called `something` the first command will resort to the behaviour of the second. Can we disable this behaviour?

Comment: `git checkout something --` seems to work.

Comment: this may even be a bug or an unwanted feature. The documentation (at least for my version, `2.6.2`) does not mention this behavior at all (`git checkout --help` if you care to verify, the section `git checkout <branch>` does not describe what should happen if the branch is missing but a file with the same name is there). Did you check https://github.com/git/git if your issue is known?

Comment: my super-bad. reading more carefully the documentation, in the `examples` section you can find the case described.